# Como comparar o valor de uma variável com uma string no shell script

Tags: linux, bash

Bom, eu estou tentando fazer uma comparação assim mas o bash esta interpretando como se fosse um comando

```
if "$V1" = "sim"
then
  ...
```

como eu comparo o valor do V1 com a string "sim":

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A sintaxe do seu if está incorreta, o certo é:

```
if [ "$V1" = "sim" ]; then
....
```

Comment: O operador não seria o de comparação/igualdade (`==`) ao invés do operador de atribuição (`=`) ?

Comment: @Lacobus se tratando de string é assim.

Answer (score 5):

**1)** Bloco simples:

```
if [ "$V1" == "sim" ]; then
    echo "Sim!"
fi
```

Em uma linha:

```
[ "$V1" == "sim" ] && echo "Sim!"
```

**2)** Bloco `if/else`:

```
if [ "$V1" == "sim" ]; then
    echo "Sim!"
else
    echo "Nao!"
fi
```

Em uma linha:

```
[ "$V1" == "sim" ] && echo "Sim!" || echo "Nao!"
```